# App Inventor query

Tags: android, app-inventor

I have a simple four button menu on my opening screen of my tentative road safety application on the **App Inventor**. What do I do with the 'screenName' and 'startValue' variables?

- The first button of my app directs you to a plain tips screen with numerous simple text tips in driving.
- The second button of the opening screen will give a searchable list of applicable fines to traffic violations. How do I implement these lists. Do I use an internal DB, fusion tables or Web DB?
- The third button button gives us a list of emergency numbers wherein I plan to use the MakePhoneCall() feature.
- The last one is a road sign quiz on the lines of the popular logo quiz. 
  This is what it looks like :) http://oi58.tinypic.com/mb1xja.jpg

So, **how do I implement the lists** using the DB and **how do I link screens** or rather, the buttons to various screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **multiple screen** apps, see the [Manager Screen Demonstration](http://puravidaapps.com/manager.php) and [Tribblehunter's Multiple Screen Method](http://puravidaapps.com/tribblehunter.php).

For **Working with lists**, see [here](http://www.appinventorblocks.com/appinventor-tutorials-tips/appinventor-lists). 
Your data is static, which means, you could store it in global variables in lists and read it from there, in this case no database is necessary.

**Btw, it also helps to do the [tutorials](http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/tutorials.html) first to learn the basics of App Inventor.**

Comment: And oh, just one more question. How do I implement a notifier style pop up with an image and some text (when an image button is clicked)?

Comment: I'm sorry, in App Inventor there are only text notifiers possible without images...

Comment: I see. Someone suggested that I use HTML with CSS within the app itself. Any idea how that is done? Do I have to user the web viewer?

Comment: Thank you! Should be smooth sailing from here on :)